# Determine source of code that is making a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Exist any way to know the source page that is calling the query and store it?

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I think HTTP_REFER is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! So fast reply!!

Comment: If you're more comfortable with Spanish, that's fine, but do use the [Spanish site](http://es.stackoverflow.com) for such questions.

Comment: You could try https://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ?

Check also `print_r($_SERVER)` if something is more accurate for what you need

Comment: Thanks! So fast reply!!